# boot2docker not starting in macOS Sierra

Tags: docker, boot2docker, macos-sierra

Any idea what this error means? My boot2docker does not start after I upgrade to macOS Sierra from El Capitan.

**Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.6.2
Git commit: cb2c3bc**

```
boot2docker up
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
...................................unexpected fault address 0xde298ca7dd
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xa code=0x2 addr=0xde298ca7dd pc=0x4e914]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.gothrow(0x387b20, 0x5)
    /usr/src/go/src/runtime/panic.go:503 +0x8e fp=0xc208099390 sp=0xc208099378
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/src/go/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:23 +0x19e fp=0xc2080993e0 sp=0xc208099390
runtime.aeshashbody(0xc2080994f8, 0x10, 0x5edfbde5, 0xc208000120)
    /usr/src/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:915 +0x74 fp=0xc2080993e8 sp=0xc2080993e0
runtime.mapassign1(0x296340, 0xc2080b4ab0, 0xc2080994f8, 0xc2080994f0)
    /usr/src/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:396 +0xce fp=0xc208099488 sp=0xc2080993e8
net.(*singleflight).DoChan(0x52f3c0, 0xde298ca7dd, 0x9, 0xc2080bc720, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/singleflight.go:81 +0x3c7 fp=0xc208099550 sp=0xc208099488
net.lookupIPDeadline(0xc208033160, 0x9, 0xe7791f701, 0x0, 0x52fe00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/lookup.go:80 +0x312 fp=0xc208099788 sp=0xc208099550
net.resolveInternetAddr(0x38d100, 0x3, 0xc208033160, 0xe, 0xe7791f701, 0x0, 0x52fe00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/ipsock.go:285 +0x49b fp=0xc2080998a0 sp=0xc208099788
net.resolveAddr(0x387000, 0x4, 0x38d100, 0x3, 0xc208033160, 0xe, 0xe7791f701, 0xc200000000, 0x52fe00, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/dial.go:110 +0x378 fp=0xc208099948 sp=0xc2080998a0
net.(*Dialer).Dial(0xc2080c8780, 0x38d100, 0x3, 0xc208033160, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/dial.go:158 +0xf6 fp=0xc208099a90 sp=0xc208099948
net.DialTimeout(0x38d100, 0x3, 0xc208033160, 0xe, 0x3b9aca00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/dial.go:150 +0xe6 fp=0xc208099b28 sp=0xc208099a90
main.read(0xc208033160, 0xe, 0x1, 0x11e1a300, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/util.go:36 +0x206 fp=0xc208099c58 sp=0xc208099b28
main.cmdUp(0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/cmds.go:101 +0x11bf fp=0xc208099df8 sp=0xc208099c58
main.run(0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/main.go:53 +0x305 fp=0xc208099ee0 sp=0xc208099df8
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/main.go:29 +0x27 fp=0xc208099f98 sp=0xc208099ee0
runtime.main()
    /usr/src/go/src/runtime/proc.go:63 +0xf3 fp=0xc208099fe0 sp=0xc208099f98
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/src/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1 fp=0xc208099fe8 sp=0xc208099fe0
```

Answer (score 1):

boot2docker was replaced with DockerToolbox, just install the latest version:
https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox